# Updating Android SDK manager with higher api

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I have android API-7, 8 and 10. Now I want to add API-16 on my SDK manager, somebody plz suggest how can I add it... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to convert target of your project or give support in your project upto API-16 or you just want to install API-16 from your SDK Manager??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start your SDK Manager, select the desired API and click "download packages". Where is the problem?

[image]